# wordpress CSS styles - footer border do not show

Tags: css

I have made simple wordpress layout and the border-bottom in footer do not show. Here is the part of the code of my `style.css` file:

```
.site-header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}

.site-footer {
    border-top: 20px solid #999;
}
```

The header border shows correctly but the footer doesn't. Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: are you using default theme or custom theme?

Comment: I am creating my own theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have add below the class ?

> "site-footer"

In footer section like

```
<header class="site-header">
```

Please check.

Comment: I have written <footer class="site_footer"> with the typo "_" instead of "-". Thank you.

Comment: ok so now you can see the border of footer?

Comment: I can see the footer, the header was ok

Answer (score 1):

Seems like either

wp_head()  or

wp_footer() is missing

Please check your header.php & footer.php for the above 2 functions in case you have enqueued styles from functions.php

Comment: Could you please look at the code below, I have pasted it as an answer because of long text. I hope I have the wp_head() and wp_footer() in suitable files but maybe something is missing there :(

Answer (score 1):

`wp_footer()` and `wp_head()` seems to be corrent. I can see in your code, that you've added the css class to the header (`<header class="site-header">`). But i cannot see the beginning of the `<footer>` element. Did you add the css class correctly to the footer element?

Comment: There was typo:
header OK: <header class="site-header">
footer nOK: <footer class="site_footer">
I have written "_" instead of "-". Thanks to your answer I have finally found it. Thank you.

Comment: So if it works now, you maybe could accept the answer of @Tarun modi or my answer as solution :)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know how the forum works. I wish I could accept both answers :-)